# Angular 1.x Kendo UI Filters

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm looking for a way to apply multiple filters in Kendo UI. The documentation doesn't seem to do very good job at explaining how to do that. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna add many filters, you need to see the documentation of 
 [kendo dataSource](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter.filters), there explains how to do it.